# Centos 7 / phpmyadmin “Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.”

Tags: virtualbox, apache-2.4, centos7

I'm running CentOS 7 in Virtualbox.

phpMyAdmin.conf for Apache:

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
#
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from 192.168.99.4
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

But when I try to access it i get the

```
You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin/ on this server.
```

Message.

From Apache log files:

```
[Sun Apr 12 16:04:09.706459 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 3114] [client 192.168.99.4:50856] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
[Sun Apr 12 16:04:10.618024 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 3114] [client 192.168.99.4:50856] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
```

I explicitely allowed my IP access to it.

selinux is already disabled.

What can cause this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from 192.168.99.4
</Directory>
```

Change to

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from All
        Allow from 192.168.99.4
</Directory>
```